# WordPress Images | How to get the cropped image?

Tags: images

I have the URL of an image (full size). During the upload it already generates a smaller version (I added this in functions). How can I get this cropped version when I have the full size URL?

The Image is not in a post so I can't use `post-thumbanil()`.
The image is in a slider on the Homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the attachment (image) id, you ca use :

```
 wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size);
```

where $size is the smaller version you want. (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

If you don't know the attachment id you may query the database for full image size url :
http://pippinsplugins.com/retrieve-attachment-id-from-image-url/

Comment: Thank you. Exactly something I was looking for. This helped me a lot.